# Shall I keep the deb file created by checkinstall after I install from the deb file?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I have an old version emacs on my Ubuntu 12.04. I built the latest emacs from its source, and used checkinstall to create a deb package, and installed emacs from the deb file. Will it be good to keep the deb file? My space is very limited nonetheless.

How about the source files? If yes,  what source files to keep?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't keep the deb file, it means that if you want to reinstall the package in the future (for example, because you uninstalled it by accident) you will have to repeat the whole process, i.e. compile from source and create the package. You must decide whether saving space is more important to you than pontentially saving time in the future.

The source tree is only needed for building the package. Once the package has been built it can be safely deleted, but again keeping it may save time in case you want to rebuild the package.